Thermal expansion of a test tube
Suppose, I have a test tube of length $L$ and cross-sectional area $A$. The coefficient of linear expansion is '$y$'. I increase the temperature by $\Delta T$.

Will the length and cross-sectional area both change?
If yes, then by how much?

My guess is that both will change as: length by $L y  \Delta{T}$ and cross-sectional area by:
$$2 L A  \Delta{T} \ .$$

I think in your area equation, the L should be an A.

In general thermal expansion applies to length, area and volumetric change, but to know how much area will expand,- you will need to know expansion coefficient for area, which is defined as $\alpha _{A}={\frac {1}{A}},{\frac {\mathrm {d} A}{\mathrm {d} T}}$.
